# RSelenium rsDriver peer SSL certificate issue

Tags: r, selenium, ssl, connection, certificate

I am trying to learn using RSelenium. I am stuck with just trying to start the server using rsDriver. I am simply trying to run the code below and got the following error:

```
rD <- rsDriver()
checking Selenium Server versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : 
  Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates
```

I searched around stack overflow and found out we can give options to rsDriver using below but I still got error:

```
my_extra <- list("--ignore-ssl-errors=true", "--ssl-protocol=tlsv1", "--web-security=no")
rs <- rsDriver(extraCapabilities = my_extra)
checking Selenium Server versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : 
  Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates
```

Is there anything else I am missing?

for httr::GET function, I am able to bypass the SSL Certificate using:

```
set_config(config(ssl_verifypeer=0L)).
```

But this method does not work for RSelenium::rsDriver.

Here is my system spec:
My OS: Microsoft Windows 10

```
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RCurl_1.95-4.8  bitops_1.0-6    httr_1.2.1      wdman_0.2.2    
[5] RSelenium_1.7.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.12     XML_3.98-1.9     binman_0.1.0     assertthat_0.2.0
 [5] R6_2.2.2         jsonlite_1.5     semver_0.2.0     curl_2.7        
 [9] tools_3.4.1      yaml_2.1.14      compiler_3.4.1   caTools_1.17.1  
[13] openssl_0.9.6
```

Comment: See https://github.com/johndharrison/wdman/issues/9

Comment: I tried this command: **httr::with_config(config(ssl_verifypeer=0L),wdman::selenium(retcommand=TRUE))**. But still it doesn't work. Exact same error: Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates. Is there any alternative way of starting the server? Maybe using some other method which I can pass an "ignore SSL certificate" command?

Comment: The issue is with `jsonlite::fromJSON`. The underlying package `curl` needs to be passed the `ssl_verifypeer` argument. In the issue given you can do this by mocking the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rsDriver` uses the binman package to handle the downloading of relevant binaries. The selenium project lists its release in a JSON file at https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/selenium-release/o
You should have the same issue if you try:

```
jsonlite::fromJSON("https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/selenium-release/o")
```

You can `mock` the relevant `curl` fundtion using something like:

```
my_new_handle <- function(...){
  print("mocking")
  h <- .Call(curl:::R_new_handle, PACKAGE = "curl")
  curl:::handle_setopt(h, ..., ssl_verifypeer = FALSE)
  h
}
testthat::with_mock(
  `curl::new_handle` = my_new_handle,
  {
    selCommand <- httr::with_config(config(ssl_verifypeer=0L),wdman::selenium(‌​retcommand=TRUE))
  }
)
```

Comment: You're right. I do get the same issue with jsonlite. However, I manage to download seleniumserver, chromedriver, firefoxdriver, and phantomjs using the set functions you provided. Do I have to keep using the mocking command as well with rsDriver?

Comment: Once the drivers are downloaded you can set `check = FALSE` as an argument in `rsDriver` and it shouldn't check for updated drivers.

Comment: I put in the check = FALSE but rsDriver still checks for selenium server versions. (I know this digress a bit from my original question. But I am still just trying to make rsDriver work.)

Comment: The check argument was being incorrectly passed in the RSelenium version on CRAN. Use the dev version from github. `devtools::install_github("ropensci/RSelenium")`. See https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/123

Comment: Thanks! I downloaded the package and it does work. But when I try to initiate rD <- rsdriver(check=FALSE), it returns this error : Error in `[.data.frame`(as.data.frame(x[["client"]]$sessionInfo), c("browserName",  : 
  undefined columns selected. Sorry to disturb you with so many questions but feels like just getting this line to work is a bit tough.